# No response obtained on a flag

Tags: support, flagging, specific-flag

Several days ago, I flagged (a question - [#647717] or could be a response to that question) for the in-correctness of interpreting the definition of 'slant height'.

According to my experience, even the flagged content was declined, I could still receive a response from the moderator; but not this time.

Is it lost? Or time is needed for the investigation?

Comment: Please give reason for the downvote.

Comment: Related: [Should moderators intervene when the accepted answer is blatantly wrong?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10133/should-moderators-intervene-when-the-accepted-answer-is-blatantly-wrong) and [How does one inform readers of a question with answers that there are serious mathematical problems with the answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8557/how-does-one-inform-readers-of-a-question-with-answers-that-there-are-serious-ma).

Comment: Also related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2473/1543

Comment: I did not downvote.  But understand that in meta, it is somewhat accepted that downvotes mean that the downvoter disagrees with the poster.  (This is not the same as in the main site, where downvotes mean the question is unclear or not useful.)

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Thanks for the helping hand. I thought the question is purely asking for something that I have the right to know. To some, the required information is right before their very eyes, but to others that information has been masked and is more than just a few clicks away.

Answer (score 10):

In general, the ♦-moderators do not moderate the *mathematical* content of the site. We're not here to ensure users employ the correct mathematical definitions, notations, or conventions. We're not even here to ensure that the answers provided are correct.

Regarding the specific flag you mention raised on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647848/8348): it was declined, by myself, on Jan 23rd, less than 90 minutes after you raised it.  I declined it with the following comment (which you should be able to access by clicking on the number(s) next to the "helpful flags" item in your user profile):

> This should have been a comment to the post.

In general, when you see things that are possibly mathematically incorrect (or using the wrong definition, convention, etc.), you should comment on the respective post pointing this out (or requesting clarification, or whatever). This will allow you to engage with that other user, and find out what the source of the disagreement is (and maybe everyone learns something!). I am personally at a loss about what you even expected the ♦-moderators to do in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful message. At least, I now know where to find the reply and also the job of the moderators is not acting like a referee. However, it is sad to see that I, as a relatively new user who knows nothing too much about the rules of this site but still likes to nose around, got down-voted by asking something that I have the right to know.

Comment: @Mick: Votes on meta are different. They are for disagreeing with the the idea, or the tone, of the post. Note that these votes do not affect reputation either. Don't take it too harshly, it just means that people found your post disagreeable for one reason or another.

Comment: Fine and thankyou.